# how to return from the background worker to web UI in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, backgroundworker

background worker in asp.net does not write the content to the web UI when background worker completed. please tell me the reasons why. and how to recover.???

```
static BackgroundWorker bwProcess; 

[WebMethod()]
public static int GetProgress()
{
      return Percentage;
}
```

background worker starts when click event happen

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bwProcess = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };

        bwProcess.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bwProcess_DoWork);
        bwProcess.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bwProcess_ProgressChanged);
        bwProcess.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bwProcess_RunWorkerCompleted);

        bwProcess.RunWorkerAsync("AsyncWorker");
    }
```

do work event for the backgroundworker

```
void bwProcess_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            bwProcess.ReportProgress(1);
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                if (bwProcess.CancellationPending) 
                { 
                    e.Cancel = true; 
                    return;
                }
                bwProcess.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            e.Result = "100 %";
        }
```

this part is not working. it run nut there is no response

```
void bwProcess_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            Response.WriteFile("D:\\Samples.xlsx");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've passed something to e.Result in DoWork, but you don't anything with it in RunWorkerCompleted.

```
void bwProcess_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     var text = e.Result as string;
     Response.Write(text);
     Response.WriteFile("D:\\Samples.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: but this is not working . that means there is no response to client from server. nothing happened while write somthing